# URL rewrite to index.php and remove .php extension with web.config on IIS7

Tags: php, url-rewriting, iis-7, web-config

I want to achieve the following -

1. Redirect all request to index.php page.
2. Want to hide .php from url but my web page should also be accessible with .php extension.
3. Should load images, css, js files.
4. In some cases I have also seen there is infinite loop. How to avoid this?

I am using below **web.config** and point#1 & 3 working fine but having problem with point#2. It hides .php but gives 500 internal server error when I add .php in url also give 500 internal error when I add .php in form action.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <defaultDocument enabled="true">
      <files>
        <clear/>
        <add value="index.php" />
        <add value="default.html" />
      </files>
    </defaultDocument>
    <security>
      <authentication>
        <basicAuthentication enabled="true" />
      </authentication>
    </security>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
      <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
      <error statusCode="404" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/test.html" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
    </httpErrors>


    <rewrite>
      <rules>

        <rule name="RewritePHP">
          <match url="(.*)" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="?path={R:1}" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^(.*)$" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}.php" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```